# Complex series bounded proof

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Problem: Prove that $\{\sum_{k=1}^n z^k\}$ is bounded where |z|= 1,$z\neq 1$

My attempt: $z = |z|e^{i\theta}= e^{i\theta}$ $$\sum_{k=1}^n z^k = e^{i\theta}+e^{2i\theta}+\cdots +e^{ni\theta}= e^{i\theta}*\frac{e^{in\theta}-1}{e^{i\theta}-1}= (1+ \frac{1}{e^{i\theta}-1})*(e^{in\theta}-1)$$

$z \neq 1\rightarrow e^{i\theta} -1\neq 0$
 and $e^{i\theta} = \cos (\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ which are bounded on $[-1,1]$. Same as $e^{in \theta}$. Hence the product is bounded. Am I right? Please, help me out.

Comment: Have you considered the triangle inequality?

Comment: You meant | sum a_n| < sum |a_n| and then the sum |a_n| is bounded? but even |z| =1, sum 1 = n , right? and it is not bounded.

Answer (score 0):

We have $e^{i\theta} - 1 = 2e^{i\theta/2}\sin(\theta/2)$ and

$$(*)\quad e^{i\theta}\cdot \frac{e^{in\theta} - 1}{e^{i\theta} - 1} = e^{i\theta/2}\cdot \frac{e^{in\theta}-1}{2\sin(\theta/2)}.$$

Now $|e^{i\theta/2}| = 1$ and by the triangle inequality, $|e^{in\theta} - 1| \le |e^{in\theta}| + 1 = 2$. So the right-hand side of $(*)$ is bounded by $|\csc(\theta/2)|$. Therefore, your sequence is bounded by $|\csc(\theta/2)|$.